# Creating Rich Text Templates

Tags: c#, rtf, rich-text-editor

I need to create a Rich Text Format (RTF) template file I can pass data through which generates the RAW rich text (that can then be saved).

- I see a TON of HTML editors...I don't want that.
- I need something to create the actual RTF...raw!
- I will save that raw RTF as a template

Having a hard time finding something.  Thanks

**FOR EXAMPLE:**
I need the raw RTF for a template...I DO NOT want HTML

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\uc1\deff0{\fonttbl
{\f0\fnil\fcharset0\fprq2 Arial;}
{\f1\fswiss\fcharset0\fprq2 Tahoma;}
{\f2\froman\fcharset2\fprq2 Symbol;}}
{\colortbl;}
{\stylesheet{\s0\itap0\nowidctlpar\f0\fs24 [Normal];}{\*\cs10\additive Default Paragraph Font;}}
{\*\generator TX_RTF32 19.0.542.500;}
\paperw7315\paperh15840\margl0\margt0\margr0\margb0\deftab1134\widowctrl\lytexcttp\formshade\sectd
\headery720\footery720\pgwsxn7315\pghsxn15840\marglsxn0\margtsxn0\margrsxn0\margbsxn0\pgbrdropt32\pard\itap0\nowidctlpar\plain\f1\fs20 MED BILL INV#  28989293\par }
```

Comment: So what is the issue/problem/question?

Comment: I need to create a TEMPLATE.  Once I have a template (in RTF)...I can pass my data across it (usuing find-and-replace) and render the RFT Report from the template.  Thanks

Comment: Create the RTF document, add `{{PLACEHOLDER_XXX}}` text for the dynamic bits, then replace them with the real values as needed.

Comment: Understood...I was hoping for a tool that would create the initial template for me (that's all).  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry... Your question is not very clear...

What about:

```
richTextBox1.SaveFile(filename.rtf);
```

If you open that file with Notepad you'll see something like:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1040{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Microsoft Sans Serif;}}
\viewkind4\uc1\pard\b\i\f0\fs36\par
}
```

Comment: This is more heavy lifting than I hoped for.  But thanks for the idea...I was hoping for an actual editor.  But this will do.